# Proper way of deallocation of double pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to add memory deallocations to old C code. 
I have a hash table of custom objects (HASHREC). After analysis of current code and reading other SO questions, I know that I need to provide three levels of deallocations. Fist - word member, next HASHREC*, and then HASHREC**.

My version of *free_table()* function frees mentioned objects. Unfortunately, Valgrind still complains that some bytes are lost.

I am not able to provide full code, it will be too long, but I am presenting how HASHREC **vocab_hash is filled inside *inithashtable()* and  *hashinsert()*. 
Could you give me a suggestion how should I fix free_table()?

```
typedef struct hashrec {
    char *word;
    long long count;
    struct hashrec *next;
} HASHREC;

HASHREC ** inithashtable() {
    int i;
    HASHREC **ht;
    ht = (HASHREC **) malloc( sizeof(HASHREC *) * TSIZE );
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++) ht[i] = (HASHREC *) NULL;
    return ht;
}

void hashinsert(HASHREC **ht, char *w) {
    HASHREC     *htmp, *hprv;
    unsigned int hval = HASHFN(w, TSIZE, SEED);

    for (hprv = NULL, htmp = ht[hval]; htmp != NULL && scmp(htmp->word, w) != 0; hprv = htmp, htmp = htmp->next);
    if (htmp == NULL) {
        htmp = (HASHREC *) malloc( sizeof(HASHREC) );  //<-------- problematic allocation (Valgrind note)
        htmp->word = (char *) malloc( strlen(w) + 1 );
        strcpy(htmp->word, w);
        htmp->next = NULL;
        if ( hprv==NULL ) ht[hval] = htmp;
        else hprv->next = htmp;
    }
    else {/* new records are not moved to front */
        htmp->count++;
        if (hprv != NULL) { /* move to front on access */
            hprv->next = htmp->next;
            htmp->next = ht[hval];
            ht[hval] = htmp;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void free_table(HASHREC **ht) {
    int i;
    HASHREC* current;
    HASHREC* tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++){
        current = ht[i];
        while(current != NULL) {
            tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tmp->word);
        }
        free(ht[i]);
    }
    free(ht);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    HASHREC **vocab_hash = inithashtable();
    // ...
    hashinsert(vocab_hash, w);
    //....
    free_table(vocab_hash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Unfortunately, Valgrind still complains that some bytes are lost"* - What *specifically* valgrind is complaining about (the actual code where the allocation it claims is leaked) should be part of your posted question. Assuming you're building with debug symbols, valgrind should be announcing *exactly* which `malloc` calls in the above code appear to be leaking, and that is where you should be focusing. I'm confident Sami is correct in the posted answer, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks for the comment, I marked the above line pointed by Valgrind with "<-----", but next time I will also add output from mem check.

Comment: You have a decent amount replicated here. Looks like you only need `TSIZE`, `HASHFN`, `SEED`, `scmp`, and `w`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the problem is here:

```
current = ht[i];
while(current != NULL) {
    tmp = current;
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp->word);
}
free(ht[i]);
```

You release the `word` but you don’t release `tmp`. After you release the first item in the linked list but not the others which causes a leak.

Free `tmp` in there and don’t free `ht[i]` after since it’s already freed here.

```
current = ht[i];
while(current != NULL) {
    tmp = current;
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp->word);
    free(tmp);
}
```